# Printing from nrepl.el to repl-y or vice versa

Tags: clojure

Given the following scenario -

- From a `lein repl` ([repl-y](https://github.com/trptcolin/reply/)) session on the terminal emulator:

  `(def reply-out *out*)`
- Then from a [nrepl.el](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el) session on Emacs:

  `(def nrepl-out *out*)`

Both vars will have different values as they will operate on different targets.

But now, if I perform in Emacs:

```
(binding [*out* reply-out] (println :foo))
```

the value will be printed on Emacs rather than on the terminal emulator as desired/expected. The opposite does not work either.

**How to print values from one repl to the other?**

**Update**: using Emacs 24 on a Llinux box, tested with xterm and gnome-terminal. Tried as well using the `println` method of each `PrintWriter` object.

Comment: It (`:foo`) does get printed in terminal whereas in emacs nrepl it shows the return value i.e nil.

Answer (score 0):

This will print to the repl that is running the underlying Clojure process:

```
 (binding [*out* (clojure.java.io/writer System/out)]
     (println :bar))
```

It is not a flexible solution though so an actual answer to my question would be much welcome.